# Comando SQL bloqueando requisições do controller em C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net

Estou implementando em um projeto C# MVC, uma rotina para executar o restore do banco de dados.

Estou com problema que quando começo a fazer o restore, as requisições de outros `controllers` ficam travadas, esperando o SQL terminar.

O que achei estranho é que se estiver em modo de debug com breakpoint dentros das `actions` não trava, mas publicado, **trava**.

#### Minha controller

```
public class DBController : AsyncController 
{

    string configCoxenao = "Data Source=VSRV-SQL2016; Initial Catalog=master; User Id=sa;Password=pass; MultipleActiveResultSets=True";

    public ActionResult SQLServer()
    {
        var lista = new List<string>();
        var listaFinal = new List<string>();

        using (SqlConnection conexao = new SqlConnection(configCoxenao))
        {
            var sql = "select * from sys.databases where name not in ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb')";
            var sqlFilial = "select top 1 EF_NOME from [{0}].dbo.FILIAL";

            conexao.Open();

            var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conexao);                
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {                    
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    lista.Add(reader["name"].ToString());
                }
            }

            foreach (var item in lista)
            {

                try
                {
                    var cmdFilial = new SqlCommand(String.Format(sqlFilial, item), conexao);
                    using (var readerFilial = cmdFilial.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (readerFilial.Read())
                        {
                            listaFinal.Add("<b>" + item + "</b> - " + readerFilial["EF_NOME"].ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    listaFinal.Add(item);
                }
            }                
        }

        return View(listaFinal);
    }

    public async Task<ActionResult> SQLServerRestore()
    {
        var lista = new List<string>();

        using (SqlConnection conexao = new SqlConnection(configCoxenao))
        {
            var sql =
                "select " +
                "  session_id as SPID, " +
                "  command, " +
                "  SUBSTRING(a.text, 19, CHARINDEX(' ', a.text, 19) - 19) as BancoDeDados, " +
                "  convert(varchar(10), start_time,  103) + ' ' + convert(varchar(10), start_time,  114) DataHoraInicio, " +
                "  percent_complete PercComplentado, " +
                "  convert(varchar(10), dateadd(second,estimated_completion_time/1000, getdate()), 103) + ' ' + " +
                "  convert(varchar(10), dateadd(second,estimated_completion_time/1000, getdate()), 114)  as DataHoraEstmidaFim " +
                "from " +
                "  sys.dm_exec_requests r  " +
                "  CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) a  " +
                "where  " +
                "  r.command in ('BACKUP DATABASE','RESTORE DATABASE') ";
            conexao.Open();

            var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conexao);
            using (var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    lista.Add(
                        "<b>" + reader["BancoDeDados"].ToString() + "</b> " +
                        reader["PercComplentado"].ToString() + " %<br />" +
                        "Data e Hora Início: " +
                        reader["DataHoraInicio"].ToString() + " / " +
                        "Data e Hora Fim Estimada: " + 
                        reader["DataHoraEstmidaFim"].ToString()
                    );
                }
            }
        }
        return View(lista);
    }

    public async Task<ActionResult> SQLServerExecutaRestore(string Arquivo, string Base)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conexao = new SqlConnection(configCoxenao))
        {
            var sql = String.Format("exec master.dbo.RestoreDataBase @arquivo = '{0}', @banco = '{1}'", Arquivo, Base);
            conexao.Open();

            var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conexao);
            await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
        }
        return Json("Ok", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

#### Dados adicionais

Estou conectando no banco de dados master para fazer o SQL e no Microsoft SQL Server Managemment Studio isto não ocorre. Imagem mostra a execução.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### Dados adicionais [Edição 2]

Um colega colocou abaixo que poderia ser problema com enfileiramento. Porém se iniciar o restore pela aplicação local e ir na versão publicada, não existe este problema de bloquear as transações e mostra corretamente a porcentagem concluída.

Comment: Se você estiver restaurando o banco, vai bloquear as demais requisições no banco, e qualquer action que tente acessar o banco de dados nesse intervalo será prejudicada. A aplicação vai continuar funcionando, mas o banco vai enfileirar as requisições

Comment: @RicardoPontual, estou conectando no banco de dados `master`para fazer o SQL e no Microsoft SQL Server Managemment Studio isto não ocorre. Atualizei a pergunta

Comment: Parece haver alguns problemas no código e me parece que a solução é fazer uma *query* melhor e não ficar criando *round trip*  no banco de dados.

Answer (score 0):

O restore vai bloquear as demais requisições do banco de dados, na sua máquina funciona pois o banco de dados deve ter um tamanho menor, já em produção o tamanho do banco deve ser maior, além de outros fatores, como processamento, latência (se o banco estiver hospedado em outro local).